# Command created issue

Tags: symfony

I have a command which is in production already and I suspect not to be working. The dev who worked on it is not there anymore. So I come here to find some help.

There is 2 things I don't understand.

1- The command name is inside the Controller folder... ApiController but it extends ContainerAwareCommand so I guess this is fine...

2- The command is not find, but might be related to the first point.

When I try: `php bin/console app:commandTest`

I've got his error in console:

> There are no commands defined in the "app" namespace.

```
class ApiController extends ContainerAwareCommand
{


    protected function configure () {
        $this->setName('app:commandTest');
        $this->setDescription("Some desc");
        $this->setHelp("Some help");
    }

    public function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    { // whatever }
}
```

Peoples told me this code worked when the previous dev was working on it...but I can't see how actually. I hope you can see how to do it or how to make it work.
Thanks.

EDIT: What I tried to add to my services.yaml but it's not working

```
services:
    app.command.api_controller: 
        class: AppBundle\Controller\ApiController 
            arguments: ["%command.default_name%"] 
            tags: - { name: console.command }
```

config.yaml

```
imports:
    - { resource: services.yml }
```

But doing this there is an error

> The file "/var/www/unitimmo/UniTimmo/app/config/services.yml" does not contain valid YAML

Comment: Is there a service defined for this class and tagged with `console.command`? Seems to be possible according to the [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html#registering-the-command)

Comment: Symfony version?  Symfony console commands are [documented here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html).  But it is important that you select the proper version in the upper right corner.  Things have changed.  Having a command in the controller directory (using a class with a controller prefix) is very unusual.

Comment: @Cerad Symfony V4
thomas.drbg I don't think so but I'm not sure. I thought it was automatic anyway.

Comment: Post the namespace line from you command.  That will actually help narrow down the Symfony version in  which the command was actually written.  I'm guessing this was not a new app but rather something started with an earlier version and then upgraded.  Then look in your services.yaml file and see if the defaults section matches https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#creating-configuring-services-in-the-container And if you have not already, clear the cache directories.

Comment: @Cerad namespace AppBundle\Controller; In fact I think it's Symfony 3.

Comment: Yep.  AppBundle strongly implies a Symfony 3 project.  It is possible you don't even have a defaults section which in turn means autoconfig is not enabled which in turn means that your command will not be automatically tagged.  As @thomas.drbg suggested, you will probably need to manually define the command as a service and tag it.

Comment: @Cerad I tried to add this in my services.yaml...but nothing changes

   `app.command.api_controller:
       class: AppBundle\Controller\ApiController
       arguments: ["%command.default_name%"]
       tags:
           - { name: console.command }`

Comment: Consider updating your question with your service definition since comment do not format very well.  Also include any defaults section.  Use "bin/console debug:container" to determine if your service is being created.  Might also include any constructor ApiController has since injecting the default command name is very unusual.

Comment: And if you have a Command directory then consider moving the file there and renaming it to ApiCommand.  Under older code, anything under the Command directory will get picked up as a command.

Comment: @Cerad first message updated. I haven't any Command directory sadly...if it was just me I would like to make this command again properly...

Comment: Getting closer.  Look closely [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html#adding-additional-attributes-on-tags) to see why you are getting the error message.  It is an easy fix.  Of course once you get past that error you will probably encounter at least one more error about using get on a null object.  The sad truth is, if this command used to work, then you are looking at the wrong code base.  Even if you get this command to register, you will just have many more problems.

Comment: Gosh I feel so dumb right now. In fact I had a folder Site/Site ... So I was not in the good one when I was launching the command...he couldn't find the bin folder. So stupid :(

Comment: You might be surprised at how often people look at one code base while running another.  Just one of those things.